# Postgres Query not using Index but faster with Index

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-11

Sorry if this seems to be a duplicate question. I'm using Postgres 11.6 on AWS RDS. I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.e
(
    id character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    p_id character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT e_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE TABLE public.ed
(
    e_id character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    <other columns + primary key>
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

I have an index on `ed.e_id`:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_ed_e_id
    ON public.ed USING btree
    (e_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

When I run this query:

```
select *
from ed, e
where e.id = ed.e_id
and e.p_id = '5c7cae8df6d10f1064b2eaf5';
```

(Problem persists when using `from ed inner join e on e.id = ed.e_id`)

The `explain analyze` plan is:

```
Gather  (cost=1136.68..141235.01 rows=28320 width=311) (actual time=0.456..871.155 rows=102709 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=136.68..137403.01 rows=11800 width=311) (actual time=0.241..688.095 rows=34236 loops=3)
        Hash Cond: (ed.e_id = e.id)
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on ed ed  (cost=0.00..133210.10 rows=1544610 width=218) (actual time=0.005..314.524 rows=1235269 loops=3)
        ->  Hash  (cost=135.67..135.67 rows=81 width=93) (actual time=0.125..0.126 rows=81 loops=3)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 19kB
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on e e  (cost=4.91..135.67 rows=81 width=93) (actual time=0.045..0.097 rows=81 loops=3)
                    Recheck Cond: ((p_id)::text = '5c7cae8df6d10f1064b2eaf5'::text)
                    Heap Blocks: exact=31
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_e_p_id  (cost=0.00..4.89 rows=81 width=0) (actual time=0.035..0.035 rows=81 loops=3)
                          Index Cond: ((p_id)::text = '5c7cae8df6d10f1064b2eaf5'::text)
Planning Time: 0.329 ms
Execution Time: 877.804 ms
```

With a `Parallel Seq Scan on ed` for the `ed.e_id` match.

When I `SET SESSION enable_seqscan = OFF`, the explain plan is:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.72..395895.14 rows=28320 width=311) (actual time=0.037..60.068 rows=102709 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using e_pkey on e e  (cost=0.29..917.61 rows=81 width=93) (actual time=0.019..4.995 rows=81 loops=1)
        Filter: ((p_id)::text = '5c7cae8df6d10f1064b2eaf5'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 10522
  ->  Index Scan using ix_ed_e_id on ed ed  (cost=0.43..4757.83 rows=11844 width=218) (actual time=0.013..0.334 rows=1268 loops=81)
        Index Cond: (e_id = e.id)
Planning Time: 0.273 ms
Execution Time: 64.675 ms
```

A whole order of magnitude faster (877ms vs 64ms)! I tried `VACUUM ANALYZE ed`, but that didn't help. I even tried changing `e.id` & `ed.e_id` to `UUID` type, but that didn't help either.

How can I convince Postgres to use the `ix_ed_e_id` index without setting `enable_seqscan` to off?

Comment: Looks weird. Can you add your configuration settings? Can you `VACUUM` and `ANALYZE` both tables and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thx for replying. I `VACUUM ANALYZE` both tables with no change. Is there a command to get all the configuration settings from pgAdmin? I'm using AWS RDS, so I didn't edit a config file to boot up the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that PostgreSQL is overestimating the cost of an index scan, which leads it to prefer a hash join over a nested loop join.

There are two parameters that tell PostgreSQL about the hardware and influence its estimate of the cost of an index scan:

- `random_page_cost`: the greater that is compared to `seq_page_cost`, the more expensive PostgreSQL will estimate an index scan's random I/O compared to sequential I/O. So you can lower that parameter to encourage index scans.
- `effective_cache_size`: this tells the optimizer how much memory is available for caching data. If the value is high, it will assume that indexes are cached and price index scans lower.

Perhaps adjusting these parameters will change PostgreSQL's mind here, although the cost estimates are suspiciously far apart.

Comment: `SHOW random_page_cost` -> 4

`SHOW effective_cache_size; -> 2169304kB

Comment: Start by lowering the former.

Comment: i had to set `random_page_cost` all the way down to `1` before it would use the index. is that a normal setting?

Comment: That is a good setting if random I/O is as cheap as sequential one, which is the case with SSDs.